# onchange event on dynamic table row how to add text param

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have code which allows for adding dynamic rows to a table, all working fine.
On each row I have an onchange event, one of the params in the onchange event function needs to be some static text, the word: quantity, having problems just adding the static text to the onchange event. I have tried the following:

```
onChange="postLineInput($(claim_id).val(),' + counter + ','quantity',$(this).val());"
```

causes an error

tried this:

```
onChange="postLineInput($(claim_id).val(),' + counter + ',"quantity",$(this).val());"
```

causes an error

tried this:

```
onChange="postLineInput($(claim_id).val(),' + counter + ',+ quantity +,$(this).val());"
```

causes an error

tried this:

```
onChange="postLineInput($(claim_id).val(),' + counter + ','+ quantity +',$(this).val());"
```

causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

If this `onChange=` is set up by JS, try this

```
onChange="postLineInput($(claim_id).val(),"+counter+","+quantity+",$(this).val());"
```